# Weird green lines on black parts of LCD monitor

Tags: lcd

I found this LCD monitor, it was soaked in rain, so I had to disassemble it, dry it and reassemble it. It worked perfectly fine, so I stored it safely. I took it out today, hooked it up to my PC and it was still working perfectly fine.

Then, all of a sudden, these weird green lines started appearing on parts of the image, especially on black parts.

You can't really see everthing on one photo, so I took several. The first one was taken with flash and the "Windows Settings" window looks less green, but both that window and the command line terminal below are supposed to be black.
[image]
Here you can see the "Windows Settings" window more closely. The part around the icons was actually flickering like static.
[image]
And here's a close-up of the cmd window next to the "Windows Settings" window.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the hell is going on here? It's not the PC btw, and it's not the GPU, the monitor does it even when it's disconnected, the same thing shows up on the power-on logo.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, it was the flexible flat cable issue, the connection wasn't all that good. I fixed it by carefully (*don't get fried, be careful!)* wiggling the cable while the monitor was powered on until the problem went away. Good to know for future reference.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Valid point, edited.